# How to generate XML from multiple cURL calls (with PHP)?

Tags: php, xml, curl, recursion

guys.

I'm with serious trouble trying to solve this.

**The scenario:**

Here at work we use the Vulnerability Management tool QualysGuard.
Skipping all technical details, this tool basically detects vulnerabilities in all servers and for each vulnerability in each server it creates a Ticket Number.
From the UI I can access all these tickets and download a CSV file with all of them.
The other way of doing it is by using the API.
The API uses some cURL calls to access the database and retrieve the info that I specify in the parameters.

**The method:**

I'm using a script like this to get the data:

```
<?php
$username="myUserName"; 
$password="myPassword"; 
$proxy= "myProxy";
$proxyauth = 'myProxyUser:myProxyPassword';


$url="https://qualysapi.qualys.com/msp/ticket_list.php?"; //This is the official script, provided by Qualys, for doing this task.

$postdata = "show_vuln_details=0&SINCE_TICKET_NUMBER=1&CURRENT_STATE=Open&ASSET_GROUPS=All"; 

$ch = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, $proxy);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYUSERPWD, $proxyauth);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 0); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $url); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $username . ":" . $password);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postdata); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1); 
$result = curl_exec ($ch); 

$xml = simplexml_load_string($result);
?>
```

The script above works fine. It connects to the API, pass some parameters to it and the `ticket_list.php` file generates an XML file with all I need.

**The Problems:**

**1-)** This script only allows a limit of 1000 results in the XML file it returns.
If my request has generated more than 1000 results, the script creates a TAG like this, at the end of the XML:

```
<TRUNCATION last="5066">Truncated after 1000 records</TRUNCATION>
```

In this case, I would need to execute anoter cURL call, with the parameters bellow:

```
$postdata = "show_vuln_details=0&SINCE_TICKET_NUMBER=5066&CURRENT_STATE=Open&ASSET_GROUPS=All";
```

**2-)** There are approximately 300,000 tickets in Qualys' database (cloud), and I need to download all of them and insert in MY database, which is used by an application that I'm creating. This application has some forms, which are filled by the user and a bunch of queries are run against the database.

**The doubt:**
What would be the best way for me to do the task above?
I've got some ideas, but I'm at a complete loss.
I thought:

**1-)**Create a function that does the call above, parses the xml and if the tag 
 `TRUNCATION` exists, it gets its value and call itself again, doing it recursively until a result without the tag `TRUNCATION`comes.
The problem with this one is that I weren't able to merge the XML results of each call, and I'm not sure if it would cause memory issues, since it would be needed nearly 300 cURL calls. This script would be executed automatically by using the server's cronTab in a non-business period.

**2-)** Instead of retrieving all the data, I make the forms that I've mentioned post the data to the script and make the cURL calls with the parameters that the user `POST`ed. But again I'm not sure if that would be good, since I would still need to do multiple calls, depending on the parameters that the user sends.

**3-) This is a crazy one:** Use some sort of Macro software to record me while I log in the UI, go to the page where the tickets are located, click the download button, check the CSV option and click to download again. Then, export this script to some language like python or java, create a task in the cronTab and create a script that parses the CSV downloaded and inserts the data to the database. (Crazy or not? =P )

Any help is very welcome, maybe the answer is right before my eyes and I haven't gotten yet.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I believe the proper way would involve a queue worker, however, If I were you I'd make your script grab 5 of these XML files in one execution- grab 1, insert rows, remove from memory, repeat. Then, I'd test it by running it a few times manually to see what sort of execution time and memory it requires. Once you've got a good idea of the execution time and you can see memory will not be a problem, schedule a cron for a little under double that time. If all goes well it should be about a minute between runs and you can have it all in your DB within an hour.

Comment: Hello, Mikel. Thanks for answering. The problem with this solution (which theoretically is quite good) is that the only way that I can get the data in CSV format is via the UI, not via API. So I'd need some kind of script to log in my account, navigate through the website, click some buttons and wait of the download to complete. I have no idea of how I could do this...

Comment: @AbnerMuniz Hey Abner! My fault, I meant XML. Use the API 5 times per execution. Grab the XML like you are, xpath->query to the items you want to save, foreach() them and insert them into your database. Then, clear it all from memory and repeat. Do this 5 times. The script should be able to handle 5000 inserts without too much problem. If you run into issues, consider building a single insert instead of running them individually and check the performance difference.

Comment: I see where you're geeting at, I'm just not sure if I get the repetition part. How are you suggesting I repeat the execution? By savingthe Truncation value in a variable and using a `do-while`?
Sorry, I've been thinking about this for so long that I can't think clearly right now haha

Comment: Well, you could write the a function that gets the records from a specific start number, but assumes 0. Then, in that function, near the end, if the response has a trunction tag, unset current xml and call that function again with the truncation tag's number as the start number. Each time it's called, increment a global variable, if that global variable becomes 5- exit. EDIT: Consider voting along the way- it incentivizes the help so you'll get more ;D